# Bokeh Error Model 'Slider' does not exist. This could be due to a widget or a custom model not being registered before first usage

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm working on the standard gapminder dataset and want to analyse the different parameters annually and find correlations between them.

I intend to add a slider which changes the year and drop down menus for the x and y axes which will help me pick the parameter I want on the respective axis.

```
import pandas as pd 
data=pd.read_csv('gapminder_tidy.csv',index_col='Year')
# Import the necessary modules
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# Make the ColumnDataSource: source
source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'x'       : data.loc[1970].fertility,
    'y'       : data.loc[1970].life,
    'country'      : data.loc[1970].Country,
    'pop'     : (data.loc[1970].population / 20000000) + 2,
    'region'      : data.loc[1970].region,
})

# Save the minimum and maximum values of the fertility column: xmin, xmax
xmin, xmax = min(data.fertility), max(data.fertility)

# Save the minimum and maximum values of the life expectancy column: ymin, ymax
ymin, ymax = min(data.life), max(data.life)

# Create the figure: plot
plot = figure(title='Gapminder Data for 1970', plot_height=400, plot_width=700,
          x_range=(xmin, xmax), y_range=(ymin, ymax))

# Add circle glyphs to the plot
plot.circle(x='x', y='y', fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)

# Set the x-axis label
plot.xaxis.axis_label ='Fertility (children per woman)'

# Set the y-axis label
plot.yaxis.axis_label = 'Life Expectancy (years)'
# Make a list of the unique values from the region column: regions_list
regions_list = data.region.unique().tolist()

# Import CategoricalColorMapper from bokeh.models and the Spectral6 palette 
from bokeh.palettes
from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6

# Make a color mapper: color_mapper
color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(factors=regions_list, palette=Spectral6)

# Add the color mapper to the circle glyph
plot.circle(x='x', y='y', fill_alpha=0.8, source=source,
        color=dict(field='region', transform=color_mapper), legend='region')

# Set the legend.location attribute of the plot to 'top_right'
plot.legend.location = 'top_right'

# Import the necessary modules
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import Slider

# Define the callback function: update_plot
def update_plot(attr, old, new):
# set the `yr` name to `slider.value` and `source.data = new_data`
yr = slider.value
new_data = {
    'x'       : data.loc[yr].fertility,
    'y'       : data.loc[yr].life,
    'country' : data.loc[yr].Country,
    'pop'     : (data.loc[yr].population / 20000000) + 2,
    'region'  : data.loc[yr].region,
}
source.data = new_data


# Make a slider object: slider
slider = Slider(start=1970,end=2010,step=1,value=1970,title='Year')

# Attach the callback to the 'value' property of slider
slider.on_change('value',update_plot)

# Make a row layout of widgetbox(slider) and plot and add it to the current 
document
layout = row(slider, plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

When I try to run the above code, I get the following error messages:

On my jupyter notebook

> W-1004 (BOTH_CHILD_AND_ROOT): Models should not be a document root if they are in a layout box: Figure(id='4946ee3e-fa73-46ba-add1-bbb2707e33e4', ...)

The Bokeh HTML page reads

> Bokeh Error
>   Model 'Slider' does not exist. This could be due to a widget or a custom model not being registered before first usage.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "On my Jupyter Notebook"? That code is what you'd write for a Bokeh server application, which would normally be run with the `bokeh serve` command at the command line, not just executed in a notebook cell. There are ways to embed Bokeh server apps in notebooks, but the look a bit different/require a little more work.

Comment: Here is a notebook server app example: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb

Comment: How did you fix this ?